# Force positive coefficients for Logistic Regression and LinearSVC

Tags: regression, logistic-regression, svm, logistic

Do you know what is the best way to force positive coefficients with Logistic Regression and Linear SVC using scikit learn?

for instance

```
svm = LinearSVC(loss='hinge'  )
coefficients = svm.coef_
```

Is there a way to force them to be positive numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the `clogistic` package. https://pypi.org/project/clogistic/